# Determinants in path integrals in gauge theories and geometry

Tags: quantum-field-theory, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, path-integral, ghosts

I know that in the formalism of path integral it is easy to show how determinants, corresponding to gauge fixing condition and FP ghosts, appear. But there is strict explanation of these determinants in terms of differential geometry - they appear as invariant Riemannian volume $\sim \sqrt{|g|} dx^1 \ldots dx^n$.

Where can I read about this?